# List selection in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using jQuery and my list has the following.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="testnav">
        <li class="test1"><a href="/link">Heading</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="test2"><a href="/link">Heading</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="test3"><a href="/link">Heading</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link">Sub Heading</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click the heading or sub heading I need that the corresponding text. I used the following, but it is not working.

```
$("li").bind("click", function(){
     alert( $(this).text());
});
```

What change should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close - you need to bind the event to the anchor tag and make sure that you wrap your event binding in a `$(document).ready` function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a").bind("click", function() { alert( $(this).text()); })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("li a").bind("click", function(){
     alert( $(this).text());
 });
```

The li's text is actually an A link text. So you need to get that. that would only work for the children.

I'm not sure LIs have a click event but it would have worked if you'd use the html() function instead of text():

```
 $("li").bind("click", function(){
     alert( $(this).html() );
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Though neither of the other answers are incorrect, I'd do it like this:

```
$('#testnav a').click(function(ev){
    alert($(this).text())

    //if you need to stop the browser going to the link
    // (eg you're doing something else AJAXey):
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

If the reason you were trying to attach to the `li`s directly is you want the whole thing to be "clickable", use CSS to resize your links:

```
#testnav a { display:block }
```

Depending on how you're doing it, you might need to play around making the link, li and/or ul float, and set widths.

Comment: use event delegation instead of adding lots of individual handlers